# segmentation fault caused by multiple += operators in c++?

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, quadtree

I am working on a particle gravitational interaction simulation program for c++, and I am almost to the point of it working, but I have a silly unexplainable error that is driving me crazy.

The program has 2048 particles and simulates them at 200 time steps; at each state, it updates the new positions, velocities, and accelerations of each of the particles based on the net force from all of the other particles.  Basically, here is the recursive function I wrote that iterates through the quad_tree and updates all the particle values:

```
    void iterateThroughQuadTree(double alpha, double delta_t)
    {
        std::cout << particles_count << std::endl;
        if (particles_count > 10)
        {
            //std::cout << particles_count << std::endl;
            children[0]->iterateThroughQuadTree(alpha,delta_t);
            children[1]->iterateThroughQuadTree(alpha,delta_t);
            children[2]->iterateThroughQuadTree(alpha,delta_t);
            children[3]->iterateThroughQuadTree(alpha,delta_t);
        }
        if (particles_count > 0)
        {

          std::cout << *(particles_x) << " " << *(particles_y) << " " << *(particles_vx) << " " << *(particles_vy) << std::endl;
          double acc_magnitude = 0, distance = 0, unit_vector_x = 0, unit_vector_y = 0, x_displacement = 0, y_displacement = 0, theta = 0, x_acc = 0, y_acc = 0;
          for (size_t i = 0; i < particles_count; i++) {
              double temp_x_acc = 0;
              double temp_y_acc = 0;
              for (size_t k = 0; k < particles_count; k++) {
                  if (i != k) {
                      x_displacement = particles_x[k] - particles_x[i];
                      y_displacement = particles_y[k] - particles_y[i];
                      distance = sqrt(pow(x_displacement,2) + pow(y_displacement,2));
                      unit_vector_x = x_displacement / distance;
                      unit_vector_y = y_displacement / distance;
                      acc_magnitude = particles_m[k] / pow(distance,2);
//                    //theta = atan(y_displacement/x_displacement);
                      x_acc = acc_magnitude * unit_vector_x;
                      y_acc = acc_magnitude * unit_vector_y;
//                    //x_acc = (x_displacement);
//                    //y_acc = (y_displacement);
                      temp_x_acc = temp_x_acc + x_acc;
                    //temp_y_acc = temp_y_acc + y_acc;
                  }
              }
              //std::cout << temp_x_acc << " " << temp_y_acc << std::endl;
              particles_x[i] += ((particles_vx[i]*delta_t) + alpha*temp_x_acc*pow(delta_t,2));
              particles_y[i] += ((particles_vy[i]*delta_t) + alpha*temp_y_acc*pow(delta_t,2));
              particles_vx[i] += 2*alpha*temp_x_acc*delta_t;
              particles_vy[i] += + 2*alpha*temp_y_acc*delta_t;
//            if (i < 1) {
//                //std::cout << *(particles_x + i) << " ";
//            }
          }
        }
    }
```

If you pay attention two the following two lines in the middle of the function:

```
temp_x_acc = temp_x_acc + x_acc;
//temp_y_acc = temp_y_acc + y_acc;
```

The error is that if one of these lines is commented out (it doesn't matter which one), the program works fine.  But when they are both uncommented, the program crashes after a few iterations giving a segmentation fault.  I used ValGrind Memcheck and it says there is a stack overflow. I don't see why both of the lines can't be in the program together; one simply sums up all of the x-component accelerations, and one sums the y-component accelerations.  Is there some type of memory problem when I have two += operators?  I have tried re-initializing the variables every time, but I still get the same result.  If you have any idea as to why this is happening, could you please explain it to me?  Thanks, I appreciate your help.

I will post additional code for the program if needed, the problem is that the program is big so I don't want to post more than that which is needed.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in this code; it's very difficult to say more without being able to reproduce the error. I understand that posting the whole program would be impractical, but you could try to reduce it to a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org); there's a good chance that you would discover the bug yourself in the process, and in any case you'd arrive at a version short enough to post whole.

Comment: The fact that it's a stack overflow gives you an idea of where to start.  Are you sure your recursion is bounded?  Is `particles_count` being correctly set when you construct the quadtree?  Are all the arrays being allocated properly?  No copy-paste errors in the allocation?  It could be undefined behaviour from invalid pointer access, rather than an actual stack overflow.

Comment: @Beta: I hesitate to post the code because it is not mine.  The assignment was partially completed by the TA, and our assignment is to complete the missing code.  The code I posted is what I wrote.  Also, it is a behemoth of a program (6 source files and 4 headers).  So, let me try to work on it some more myself and if I get an answer I will update.

Comment: @paddy: I think everything is fine, I have been through the program up and down, and I don't see how the errors you hypothesize would explain why the program works when one of the highlighted lines is commented out.

Comment: Your function outputs something every time it's called.  How does the output differ in the broken case?  Does this really look like a stack overflow in this function?  Are you certain that the function itself is to blame?

Comment: Here's another thought.  There's a potential divide-by-zero in there.  You should check that `distance` is not zero.  If the data was set up to cause this to happen, then if you are calculating it properly you might fall into the trap. =)  The other thing to consider is that very small distances can make very large accelerations, driving your particles a very long way from each other.  Depending on how your tree is constructed, this might have some ramifications.

Comment: This line give me pause: `particles_vy[i] += + 2*alpha*temp_y_acc*delta_t;`

Comment: @JimR: Actually just found that myself, its a typo.  But after fixing it, I still have the same error.

Comment: You say this is a recursive function, but it is shown as a non-member function. If particles_count > 10 then you go ahead and call `children[0]->iterateThroughQuadTree(alpha,delta_t);` etc, which appears to be a member function. Is this a member function? If so, how do you tell what's a member variable and what isn't? We can't, so no way for us to tell what globals you are mishandling, etc.

Comment: @kfsone: It is a member function.

Answer (score 0):

Not having seen all of your code, I have a theory that might hold water.  Somewhere in your code that you haven't shown, you surely must be modifying the value of particles_count, which is a global variable.  Your recursive function cannot possibly terminate unless particles_count dips below 10.

Is it possible that when temp_x_acc and temp_y_acc are both set, your particles_count value somehow goes up, causing even more iterations of your loop, leading to a stack overflow?  As a sanity check to help verify, I recommend you add a static counter to the top of your function, like this:

```
static int iteration=0;
iteration++;
cerr<<"Iteration: "<<iteration<<", "<<Particles count: "<<particles_count<<endl;
```

Note the use of cerr so you get all output before it crashes.  cout might not be printing the whole story when it crashes.

Generally with recursive code, important variables like particles_count should be passed as a function parameter.  I think the value of particles_count may be changing in ways you don't anticipate.

Comment: What makes you think it's a global variable.  It looks like it's a class member to me.

Comment: @Steven: I agree with paddy, I think it's a class member.  The quadtree is a recursive object, and every child quadtree will have a lesser number of particles until the count is below 10, at which point it stops making children.

Comment: @user2826735 You *think* it's a class member? *You* have the original source and *you're* not sure whether something is a class member or not? Also, you do realize that as you return from all those child calls you will execute the second if statement's contents at each return level?

Comment: @kfsone: I was simply trying to be courteous.  It _is_ a class member. Yes, it will execute the second if statement, but its necessary for the algorithm.

Comment: OK, even if it's a class member variable, the problem remains. Usually in recursive code, the variable that controls the recursion is one of the function arguments, which is not the case in your code.  I believe your problem is that the value of particles_count is not what you expect it to be deep inside your recursion because every time that value changes, it affects all of your other recursive function calls on the stack.